# How to change hAxis (x-axis) format to HH:mm?

Tags: google-analytics, google-visualization, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Please tell me where did I go wrong.

My line chart looks like this:

[image]

**Current hAxis format:** HH (24-hr)

**Goal:** HH:MM, like so:

[image]

I've found possible answers here([Google line chart configuration](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options)), but only the title worked :(

```
hAxis: {
    title: 'MY OWN LABEL GOES HERE',
    gridlines: {
        units: {hours: {format: ['HH:mm']}}
}
```

Note: I am getting the chart using google analytics API

Answer (score 0):

try `hAxis.format`...

```
hAxis: {
    format: 'HH:mm',
    title: 'MY OWN LABEL GOES HERE'
}
```